# ASP.NET MVC5 Identity account lockout without Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, wcf, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have created an ASP.NET MVC5 application that allows users to access their financial data including invoices, services and products that they have acquired from our company.

The application gets all data from a set of WCF services including a list of all registered users that have access to the system. I'm using ASP.NET Identity object and claims to authorize users into the application, everything works fine I only have to use the credentials (email and password) to invoke the WCF service which returns an object containing the details about the User or a NULL value if there's no match.

However, there's a new requirement to implement an account lockout after 5 failed login attempts (the account will be locked for 20 minutes before allowing users to try again) which is a feature already included in ASP.NET identity 2.0. I have been "googling" for a couple of days, but couldn't find an example (or even a similar approach) of how to implement this requirement without storing users in Entity Framework and a local DB.

Is there any way of adding just the account lockout feature (with the 20 minutes lockout) using a WCF service as a datasource to my ASP.NET MVC5 application? Any ideas?

This is actually my first ASP.NET MVC5 application, so don't really know much about all features provided on it, any help will be appreciated.

This is how the Login (POST) looks like:

```
    //Authentication handler
    IAuthenticationManager Authentication
    {
        get { return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication; }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {  
                //Validate user from service
                CWP_AccountService.User userObject = AccountClient.GetUserByCredentials(model.Email, model.Password);
                if (userObject != null)
                {
                   //Create Claims
                    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(
                                new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userObject.Email) },
                                DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                                ClaimTypes.Name, ClaimTypes.Role);

                    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userObject.Email));
                    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, userObject.UserID.ToString()));

                    int cookieDurationPersistence = 20160;
                    int cookieDuration = 2;

                    Authentication.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = model.RememberMe, ExpiresUtc = (model.RememberMe) ? DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(cookieDurationPersistence) : DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(cookieDuration) }, identity);

                     //Check if there is a local return URL
                     if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                     {
                         return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                     }

                     return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                else
                {
                     ModelState.AddModelError("system-error", "The Email/Password provided is not valid.");
                } 

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("system-error", "Error");
                logger.Warn(ex.ToString());
            }                
        }


        return View(model);
    }
```

The `Startup.Auth.cs`:

```
public partial class Startup
{
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie, 
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
            });         

        }
}
```

Comment: What do you use the resultant ClaimsIdentity for?  Maybe I'm mistaken, but it sounds like you are sending the username and password with the WCF request and validating at the service side?

Comment: Not really, the AccountClient.GetUserByCredentials() function (WCF Service) only accepts email and password, and returns the user that matches both parameters. The validation takes place in the MVC side, if the UserObject is not NULL means the user is registered. I use ClaimsIdentity to have access to the user's id and email to perform authorization tasks within the app.